# ASP_0147 | 500_Server_Error

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

This issue has been happening for a while, and it's suspected to be session related since it pertains to the users browser. Opening a new browser (session) rids the issue.  The application uses Global.asa (Only Application_OnStart and Sub Session_OnEnd, the rest are empty), Classic ASP (VbScript), IIS 7.0.

This error keeps popping up on url's which happen to be loading fine, until the page is refreshed for the second time, then it bogs out and even times out. In the same browser, if i even try to open that entire website, it times out at this point. For about 350000ms and then everything starts working again. Very weird!

If anyone can help with this, I haven't had any luck anywhere finding what may be causing this, besides something that has to do with the sessions, maybe in the application pool.. I'm not sure.. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: We need more details: what exact error you get? What does the server event log contain? It might contain some extra, useful, errors.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, this is from the log. It just timesout very long, these are 200's, but it shouldn't take that long for me to re-access even the site. The 500's are either timeouts or could even be other issues from timing out. I cannot reproduce the error w/ 0147 it works fine.  All the ASP 0147 errors are at least 300000ms, its gotta be timeout related.

Comment: Might be not real browsers but some bots so I wouldn't worry too much about it. Does your log contain user agent information as well so you can verify this?

Comment: the timeout even happens to me when i refresh the same page, it gets 200 but takes 300000ms, first load only took less than 1000ms

Comment: Do you happen to have Google AdSense in your pages? Saw somewhere else that it can cause such problems sometimes..

Comment: yes i do, maybe i should disable it and see what happens.. will keep you posted. how about facebook LIKE button?

Comment: Well isn't that something GOOGLE was causing my site to lag.. Well that's off the site for now.. Just amazing.. Thanks..

Comment: Cheers, posted it as answer as well for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Google AdSense might cause such problems, disabling it should solve your issues.

To cure the real "root" of the problem and keep using AdSense, guess you'll have to contact Google.

Comment: Well lets see if i get anymore errors, i'm going to be viewing over it in the meantime and will keep posted any updates.. but for now it resolved my initial issue.. lets see.. thanks again, will be back!

Comment: It's not Adsense actually, it's something else on the server, not a front end JS. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you check with Firebug then if there's some other page trying to load?

Comment: its not a js issue, its an internal issue causing a server side error, not client side.

Comment: Sorry, no idea then. How often does it happen?